# iOS Swift: SecureEnclave encryption app crash on SecKeyGeneratePair

Tags: ios, swift, security, encryption, enclave

I am facing an issue with SecureEnclave encryption in `SecKeyGeneratePair` method.

[image]

App crash on `SecKeyGeneratePair` method, I don't know what's missing or something wrong. I am referring https://github.com/trailofbits/SecureEnclaveCrypto
See the following code snippet.

```
func generateKeyPair(accessControl: SecAccessControl) throws -> (`public`: SecureEnclaveKeyReference, `private`: SecureEnclaveKeyReference) {
        
        let privateKeyParams: [String: Any] = [
            kSecAttrLabel as String: privateLabel,
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true,
            kSecAttrAccessControl as String: accessControl,
        ]
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: attrKeyTypeEllipticCurve,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
            kSecAttrTokenID as String: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
            kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: privateKeyParams
        ]
        var publicKey, privateKey: SecKey?
        
        let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(params as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)
        
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            
            throw SecureEnclaveHelperError(message: "Could not generate keypair", osStatus: status)
        }
        
        return (public: SecureEnclaveKeyReference(publicKey!), private: SecureEnclaveKeyReference(privateKey!))
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the Demo App in Swift?

Comment: yes demo app is crashed

Comment: I think the best thing you can try is to open an issue in the github repository or search for closed issues that can match your situation